# How to render hight quality PNG with glass and glossy structure?

Tags: rendering

I have problem with png export from Blender. In my rendered mode everything is looking great, but when I click to render this png the quality is bad and my glass structure look nothing like in render mode.

Camera setting full hd

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/180bRMCFdUu-NTplt8H9l8nJKmy4ulrBn?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello could you please share the object?

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: object: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/180bRMCFdUu-NTplt8H9l8nJKmy4ulrBn?usp=drive_link   In short i wanna render high quality png but something is wrong with quality and light.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scene you have disabled the *Scene World* in *Rendered* view, i.e. what you see in the viewport is just rendered with one of Blender's internal preview HDRIs:

[image: scene world disabled]

About the quality I cannot say anything since your file comes without the HDRI packed into it, which means I only get a purple background color. But from your settings I do not necessarily expect the quality to be bad - maybe you have to elaborate what you mean by bad quality.

If you mean that it is just not the correct environment lighting, well that's not surprising since you are first of all not previewing with the original world background as I mentioned above and when you finally render the image with <kbd>F12</kbd> or *Render* > *Render Image*, it uses the world shader which you have set up, not the preview HDRI. And there you have a second problem: you have setup two *World Output* backgrounds in the shader, a new one with the "forest.exr" environment, but you did not replace the default grey background with it. So it uses the grey background for rendering instead of the EXR image. Delete the old background nodes:

[image: two background shaders]

Comment: Now looking just like i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @kacper5123 You're welcome. The best way on this site to show an answer was helpful and express your thanks is by accepting an answer ;) Read more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)